# Why am I getting a 'list index out of range error'

Tags: python, html, dataset

I have a dataset which has 12 columns here is some sample data from the dataset.

```
[['1,1412,,Correy',
  'Edmed,00:06:53,35-39,1,Male,1,WOOLLOONGABBA,00:06:54,07:15:33,07:22:27'],
 ['1000,3060,,Nathan',
  'Hankinson,00:17:33,30-34,57,Male,879,COORPAROO,00:17:34,07:58:27,08:16:01'],
 ['1000,4297,,Jason',
  'Taylor,00:17:33,40-44,107,Male,879,GEEBUNG,00:17:34,07:42:08,07:59:41'],
 ['1002,4014,,Thomas',
  'Collins,00:17:34,14-19,20,Male,881,JINDALEE,00:17:35,08:00:04,08:17:39'],
 ['1003,4146,,Avis',
  'Houlihan,00:17:35,60-69,8,Female,117,CARINDALE,00:17:36,08:00:34,08:18:09'],
 ['1003,4426,,Greg',
  'Burt,00:17:35,60-69,87,Male,882,BRISBANE,00:17:36,07:57:42,08:15:17'],
 ['1005,1352,,Amanda',
  'Wilson,00:17:38,45-49,25,Female,118,CASINO,00:17:39,07:37:43,07:55:21'],...
```

I am using 12 columns however when I put this code in to create a table it gives me index out of range

```
html_content = "<html><body><table><tr><td>" + bike_list[0][0] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][1] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][2] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][3] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][1] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][4] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][5] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][6] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][7] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][8] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][1] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][9] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][10] + "</td><td>" + bike_list[0][11] + "</td></tr>"
i=1
while i < len(bike_list):
    html_content += "<tr><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td></tr>".format(bike_list[i][0],bike_list[i][1],bike_list[i][2],bike_list[i][3],bike_list[i][4],bike_list[i][5],bike_list[i][6],bike_list[i][7],bike_list[i][8],bike_list[i][9],bike_list[i][10],bike_list[i][11])
    i+=1
html_content += "</table></body></html>"
```

Why is that so?

Comment: because your list items only have 2 elements - those are comma seaparated strings, not list items

Comment: also instead of doing the join manually why not `"<html><body><table><tr><td>" + "</td><td>".join(bike_list)`

Answer (score 2):

Because lists are 0-indexed in Python.

But this is not the way to iterate through a list. For that we have `for` loops.

Note also, you can pass the entire sublist at once by using the `*` operator.

```
for elem in bike_list:
    html_content += "<tr><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td></tr>".format(*Elem)
```